# Java consumer with return

Tags: java, consumer

I don't understand why this code is working:

```
class Resource {
    private Resource() {
        System.out.println("created...");
    }
    public Resource op1() {
        System.out.println("op1");
        return this;
    }
    public Resource op2() {
        System.out.println("op2");
        return this;
    }
    private void close() {
        System.out.println("clean up...");
    }
    public static void use(Consumer<Resource> block) {
        Resource resource = new Resource();
        try {
            block.accept(resource);
        }
        finally {
            resource.close();
        }
    }
}

// method call

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
      Consumer<Resource> block = resource -> resource.op1().op2(); //here
      Resource.use(block);
    }
}
```

Consumer should accept one parameter and return void. But in this example Consumer take one parameter(resource) and return this parameter. Why it is working although I return resource instance instead of void?

Comment: because you are returning an instance of Resource. Check the signature of the op1 and op2 methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Consumer<Resource> block = resource -> resource.op1().op2();` is equivalent to:

```
Consumer<Resource> block = new Consumer<Resource>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(Resource resource) {
            resource.op1().op2();  // there is no return statement
        }
    };
```

Comment: the question is about the op1 and op2 methods. It's even indicated as such in the question

Comment: Param of method accept should be type Resource instead of String but I understand answer. Thanks.